# When I add a custom domain, can I still access the old appname-xyzabc.dotcloud.com address?

Tags: dotcloud

When I add a domain alias to my DotCloud service, is the old appname-xyzabc.dotcloud.com address still available too? The reason I'd like to continue using it is for the SSL for internal API requests (from our mobile app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will still be available.